# Error Instantiating Prefab in while loop at end of row, Happens after a random amount of rows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm working on a simple world generator using squares. But it fails after a random number of rows, It doesn't instantiate the last item.

[image]

I can't see why it is failing as it has available block options to place in that spot. It doesn't always fail after the same amount of rows either.

It does sometimes also place the wrong blocks in places but I think that is due to another problem.
Error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: index 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.GameObject].get_Item (Int32 index
(at/Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633) GenGround.Start () (at Assets/Code/GenGround.cs:93)
```

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class GenGround: MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    public GameObject[] terrainTypes;
 void Start() {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int i = 0;
  GameObject[] itemList = new GameObject[10000];
  terrainTypes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Terrain").OrderBy(go => go.name).ToArray();
  List <GameObject> WaterDeepOpts = new List <GameObject> ();
  WaterDeepOpts.Add(terrainTypes[3]);
  WaterDeepOpts.Add(terrainTypes[4]);
  List <GameObject> WaterShallowOpts = new List <GameObject> ();
  WaterShallowOpts.Add(terrainTypes[3]);
  WaterShallowOpts.Add(terrainTypes[4]);
  WaterShallowOpts.Add(terrainTypes[1]);
  List <GameObject> SandOpts = new List <GameObject> ();
  SandOpts.Add(terrainTypes[0]);
  SandOpts.Add(terrainTypes[1]);
  SandOpts.Add(terrainTypes[4]);
  List <GameObject> GrassOpts = new List <GameObject> ();
  GrassOpts.Add(terrainTypes[0]);
  GrassOpts.Add(terrainTypes[1]);
  GrassOpts.Add(terrainTypes[2]);
  List <GameObject> StoneOpts = new List <GameObject> ();
  StoneOpts.Add(terrainTypes[0]);
  StoneOpts.Add(terrainTypes[2]);
  List <GameObject> Block1 = new List <GameObject> ();
  List <GameObject> Block2 = new List <GameObject> ();
  List <GameObject> Blocks = new List <GameObject> ();
  foreach(GameObject g in terrainTypes) {
   Debug.Log(g);
  };
  itemList[i] = Instantiate(terrainTypes[Random.Range(0, terrainTypes.Length)], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
  x = x + 10;
  i = i + 1;
  while (y < 1000) {
   if (i < 100) {
    //Debug.Log (i);
    if (itemList[i - 1].name == "WaterDeep(Clone)") {
     itemList[i] = Instantiate(WaterDeepOpts[Random.Range(0, WaterDeepOpts.Count())], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    } else if (itemList[i - 1].name == "WaterShallow(Clone)") {
     itemList[i] = Instantiate(WaterShallowOpts[Random.Range(0, WaterShallowOpts.Count())], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
     //Debug.Log (itemList [i]);
    } else if (itemList[i - 1].name == "Sand(Clone)") {

     itemList[i] = Instantiate(SandOpts[Random.Range(0, SandOpts.Count())], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    } else if (itemList[i - 1].name == "Grass(Clone)") {
     itemList[i] = Instantiate(GrassOpts[Random.Range(0, GrassOpts.Count())], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    } else if (itemList[i - 1].name == "Stone(Clone)") {
     itemList[i] = Instantiate(StoneOpts[Random.Range(0, StoneOpts.Count())], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    } else {
     itemList[i] = Instantiate(terrainTypes[Random.Range(0, terrainTypes.Length)], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }
   } else if (y > 0 && x > 0) {
    //Debug.Log(itemList[i - 1].name);
    //  Debug.Log(x);
    if (itemList[i - 1].name == "WaterDeep(Clone)") {
     Block1 = WaterDeepOpts;
    } else if (itemList[i - 1].name == "WaterShallow(Clone)") {
     Block1 = WaterShallowOpts;
    } else if (itemList[i - 1].name == "Sand(Clone)") {
     Block1 = SandOpts;
    } else if (itemList[i - 1].name == "Grass(Clone)") {
     Block1 = GrassOpts;
    } else {
     Block1 = StoneOpts;
    }
    if (itemList[i - 99].name == "WaterDeep(Clone)") {
     Block2 = WaterDeepOpts;
    } else if (itemList[i - 99].name == "WaterShallow(Clone)") {
     Block2 = WaterShallowOpts;
    } else if (itemList[i - 99].name == "Sand(Clone)") {
     Block2 = SandOpts;
    } else if (itemList[i - 99].name == "Grass(Clone)") {
     Block2 = GrassOpts;
    } else {
     Block2 = StoneOpts;
    }
    Blocks = Block1.Intersect(Block2).ToList();
    //Debug.Log(Blocks.Count());
    int d = Random.Range(0, Blocks.Count());
    //  Debug.Log(d);
//    foreach(GameObject g in Blocks) {
//     Debug.Log(g);
//    };
    Debug.Log("Blocks = " + Blocks[d].name);
    itemList[i] = Instantiate(Blocks[d], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
   } else if (y > 0 && x == 0) {
    //  Debug.Log(x);
    if (itemList[i - 99].name == "WaterDeep(Clone)") {
     //  Debug.Log("BONG!");
     Blocks = WaterDeepOpts;
    } else if (itemList[i - 99].name == "WaterShallow(Clone)") {
     //  Debug.Log("BONG!");
     Blocks = WaterShallowOpts;
    } else if (itemList[i - 99].name == "Sand(Clone)") {
     //    Debug.Log("BONG!");
     Blocks = SandOpts;
    } else if (itemList[i - 99].name == "Grass(Clone)") {
     //    Debug.Log("BONG!");
     Blocks = GrassOpts;
    } else {
     Blocks = StoneOpts;
     //  Debug.Log("BONG!");
    }
    //Blocks = Block1.Intersect(Block2).ToList();
    //  Debug.Log("BONG!");
    int d = Random.Range(0, Blocks.Count());
    Debug.Log(d);
    Debug.Log("count=" + Blocks.Count());
    itemList[i] = Instantiate(Blocks[d], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
   } else {
    itemList[i] = Instantiate(terrainTypes[Random.Range(0, terrainTypes.Length)], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
   }
   x = x + 10;
   i = i + 1;
   //Debug.Log(itemList[i]);
   if (x == 1000) {
    y = y + 10;
    x = 0;

   };

  };

 }


 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update() {

 }
}
```

Comment: at certain point terrainTypes.Length has no more elements and returns 0. Random.Range(0, 0) also returns 0 but element 0 does not exist.

Comment: @NikaKasradze After line 15 terrainTypes is only read from I don't see how it can loose elements.

Comment: Your line 93 generates the error. That should be `itemList[i] = Instantiate(Blocks[d], new Vector3(x, 0, y), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;`. This probably means that the line `Blocks = Block1.Intersect(Block2).ToList();` produces an empty list.

Comment: @GunnarB. Thanks I rechecked my maths and I had miscounted the number to remove when checking what was the block on the row below.